# Buildfire: Vibrate issue

Tags: buildfire

```
                            buildfire.notifications.vibrate({
                                milliseconds: 500
                            }, function (err, data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
                            buildfire.notifications.beep({
                                times: 1
                            }, function (err, data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
```

I am having an issue with the vibrate not working.  The beep is beeping 3 times, and no vibrate on iphone in (silent mode - off) and nothing in silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you make it 1000 milliseconds in vibrate it should work fine. iOS currently does not allow changing the duration for it.

Regarding the three beeps, that is how iOS beeps; 1 beep sounds like 3. if you make it 2 it will sound like 6.